# UITableView numberOfRowsInSection , dynamically

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

i want to have one table view same this

---

row0

### row1

---

row2

### row3

---

row4

### row5

but now with this code i have this tableview i konw i have change in numberOfRowsInSection part 
but i dont konw how

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return items.count/2;

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 2;

}
```

---

row1

### row2

---

row1

### row2

---

row1

### row2

Comment: Please try to *improve* your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765420/uitableview-dynamically-section-rows, instead of *repeating it*.

Answer (score 1):

`NSIndexSet` (or `NSMutableIndexSet`) might be what you are looking for. It "contains" other "numbers/indices" but its count is the number of items it contains regardless of the value/range of those items.

See [Apple's documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547484/nsindexset-indexatindex).
See [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547484/nsindexset-indexatindex) and [This answer why `NSIndexSet` might not be appropiate.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4547589/605977)